# JS Можно ли проверить статус NTP сервера?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ntp

Ребята, простите за тупой вопрос.

Сижу на фронте, vuejs.
Нужно проверить любой ntp сервер на доступность (например, time.google.com)
Похожего в поиске не нашел.
Это можно сделать с фронта? Или только с бэка?

Comment: NTP это UDP, поэтому с фронта никак

Comment: TCP и UDP в принципе не работают и не будут работать в браузере! Никогда!

Comment: @EugeneX ну с утверждением «никогда» спешить не стоит, уже давно существует черновик [Direct Sockets API](https://github.com/WICG/direct-sockets/blob/main/docs/explainer.md)

Comment: @andreymal да да, по той-же самой причине миру пришлось отказаться от Adobe Flash. Как раз И из-за того что он позволял напрямую работать с сокетами он перестал быть безопасной технологией. И поэтому канул в небытие.

Comment: @EugeneX ну вот Direct Sockets API предлагает *безопасную* работу с сокетами ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯